# windows10 IoT coreでサポートする.Netのバージョンについて

Tags: windows, .net, raspberry-pi, windows-10

windows10 IoT coreでサポートされている.Netはどのバージョンになるのでしょうか？
サンプルコードを見る限り.Netが使えるらしいことは分かるのですが・・・

単純な質問で申し訳無いですが、調べても言及されているページ見つけられませんでした。
よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows IoT Core で動くのはUWP, Universal Windows Platformアプリケーションです。
デスクトップの.NET Frameworkとは提供されている名前空間が異なります。.NET Coreと言われるものです。
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/mt185501.aspx

バージョン，というと少し難しいのですが，フレームワークの機能はNuGetパッケージで細分化されて提供されています。機能毎に細かくアップデートが行われています。
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/magazine/mt590967.aspx